# MT 8000 rings with 105 5800 set up

Tags: shimano, gears

has anyone tried using MT 8000 front rings with 105 5800 set up. I'm hoping I can just change the crank and rings and adjust the front  derailleur. Any advice?

Answer (score 2):

They have totally different bolt patterns, 96mm asymmetrical for 8000 and 110mm asymmetrical for 5800.

Comment: Yes, I understand that but if I change the cranks would there be any problems with compatibility with the cassette. Things lining up etc?

Comment: Its overall performance would be poor due to the profile of the road FD being intended for larger rings. Chain drop and rough shifting are common problems putting road FDs on mountain cranks.

Comment: Thanks for that, that was the sort of thing I was unsure of. Back to the drawing board

Comment: If you're trying to get lower gearing on a road bike, the way to start would be a larger cassette (which may need to get a higher capacity rear derailleur, possibly from the mountain group). Then, start faffing with the front setup (smaller chainrings, moving to a triple, whatever).

Comment: Thanks. I did look at that but I'm already on an 11-32 so to go larger would probably mean changing  my rear derailleur wouldn't it? If I do that don't mtb set ups have different pull ratios?

Answer (score 0):

[image]If you are looking for a relatively cheap and less complicated downgearing option, you could consider an XT cassette. I use an 11-40 eleven speed in conjunction with 5800 compact cranks. My rear mech is a 105 5800 with medium cage and I also installed a 'roadlink ' hanger extender. It works! If not for this hack I doubt I would have completed my recent 'everest' ride of a local climb. With the roadlink, new XT M8000 cassette and new chain all up it cost less than 80 euros. Ten minutes work to install!If you have a short cage mech, it may still work. Look up durianrider's videos on you tube to see for yourself what is possible.